# How to know container runtime version in AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am new to azure k8s. I am trying to verify if my container runtime on my aks cluster, I can only see the node details

[nodepool](https://i.imgur.com/qw3ILHp.png)

How can I get the container runtime details on my aks cluster?

I tried checking the nodepool details under the setting section but not able to find the container runtime details

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: To view your container runtime on AKS, you can either do `kubectl get nodes -o wide` or can view it from the cluster configuration on the left side of your AKS cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know your container runtime version, you can either login to your aks cluster and do a

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

[image]

From portal,

To view the container runtime version of an AKS cluster from the Azure portal,  click on the name of the AKS cluster for which you want to view the container runtime version. Check Under Node Pools.

Click on `Node pools` in the left-hand menu under the `Settings` section. This will list the node pools associated with your AKS cluster. Inspect the Node Pool.

Select a node pool to view its details. The container runtime version is typically tied to the `node image version` as shown below

[image]

Reference doc
[K8s list details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/explore/explore-intro/)